# One-dimensional heat conduction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, inverse-problems

I was reading a paper about one-dimensional heat conduction problem and I get stuck in one expression that I couldn't understand how to calculate.

First, they define the  heat conduction problem as follows:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}[q(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}]+f(x,t),\quad (x,t) \in (0,L) \times (0,T]$

with initial condition $u(x,0) = u_{0}(x)$, $0\leq x\leq L$

and Dirichlet boundary conditions

$u(0,t) = g_{1}(t), 0\leq t\leq T$,

$u(1,t) = g_{2}(t), 0\leq t\leq T$,

where $f(x,t), u_{0}(x), g_{1}(t), g_{2}(t)$, and $q(x)$ are known continuous functions.  This is considered as a direct problem. Also the diffusion coefficient is known and is given by $q(x)= p_{1}+p_{2}x+...+p_{m+1}x^{m} $, where $p_{1}..., p_{m+1}$ are constants.

For the inverse problem, the $q(x)$ is unknown. In order to estimate it they said that additional information on the boundary $x=x_{0}, 0<x_{0}<L,$ is required and they denote $u(x_{0},t) = g(t) ,  0\leq t\leq T$. Until now everything is clear.

They said that to find $q(x)$ one has to determine its coefficients $p_{1},p_{2}..., p_{m+1}$ by minimizing the error estimate (using least-squares method) :

$F(p_{1},...p_{m+1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} [u(x_{0},t_{i},p_{1},p_{2}...,p_{m+1})-g(t_{i})]^{2}$.

What i didn't understand is how can i define the expression of $u(x_{0},t_{i},p_{1},p_{2}...,p_{m+1})$ ? They mentioned that these are the calculated results and are determined from the solution of the direct problem which is given previously by using $q(x)$, but i really don't know how can i derive this expression. Note that in the forward problem one can calculate the solution $u(x,t)$ as well as $q(x)$.

I would be very thankful for your explanations !

You can find the paper here https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2014/626037/

Comment: For fixed set of parameters $p_1,\ldots,p_{m+1}$ you can compute the solution $u(t,x)$ of the direct problem. Then you just define $u(t,x,p_1,\ldots,p_{m+1}) := u(t,x)$ ($u(t,x)$ will change when you choose different parameters). By the way, something seems off in your known form of $q(x)$, could you correct it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually i understand how to use $q(x)$ to find $u(x,t)$, but i'm getting confused about the inverse problem, where the coefficients $p_{1},..,p_{m}$ are unknown and q(x) is define as $ q(x) = p_{1} +p_{2}x...p_{m+1}x^{m}$, what would be then the expression of $u(x,t,p_{1},..,p_{m})$ ?

Comment: Also, since this is the heat equation, shouldn't it be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[q(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}]$?

Answer (score 1):

If you fix a value for $p_1,\ldots,p_{m+1}$, for example $p_1 = p_2=\ldots=p_{m+1} = 1$, then you can solve the direct problem explicitly. So $u(t,x,1,\ldots,1) = u(t,x)$, where $u(t,x)$ is the solution of the direct problem with $q(x) = 1 + x + \ldots + x^{m}$.

To put it differently: in the simplified case $m=0$ we have $q(x) = p_1$. Then to see what $u(t,x,p_1)$ is, you solve the equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[p_1\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}] + f(x,t)$ (with the previous boundary/initial data). You will then get an explicit form of $u$ which somehow depends on $p_1$. Then you do the least-square optimization to see which $p_1$ works best.

Comment: Very clear ! Thank you so much for your explanations and for you time !